# How to access fields of a persist Entity in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a REST API in Haskell with the Scotty framework. I have a persist table defined as

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
User json
    username Text
    number Text
    group Text Maybe
    UniqueUsername username
    UniqueNumber number
    deriving(Show)
...
]
```

I then have a function to grab a user `fetchUserByName :: Text -> IO (Entity User)`. What I'm not understanding is that if I have a variable `user :: Entity User`, how do I access any of the fields, like username for this user? I feel like this should be completely trivial yet I can't seem to find the answer online. Or am I just going about this the wrong way? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract your User item using `entityVal`, then you can to the desired column using the record name (which I believe is always generated to be of the format of the format 
`<tablename><columnname>` in camelcase)

```
print $ userGroup $ entityVal user
```